# Wait for keypress with timeout

Tags: javascript, keypress

In an experiment I'm coding, on every trial, I need to display a stimulus (search array) and then wait for a maximum of 5 seconds for the subject to respond with a keypress. If a key is pressed, the next trial begins immediately or else after 5 seconds.

I just want to know if I can code up something like this in JavaScript, and if so, how should I code up the experiment? Also, I should be able to store the identity and timestamp of the key pressed.

Comment: This will definitely work. You most likely would use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: detecting mousedown would be easier

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var timeout;

timeout = setTimeout(next, 5000); //execute function "next" after 5000 miliseconds

//With jQuery
//$("#element").on("keypress", function(){ clearTimeout(timeout); next();} );

//Without jQuery
function elementOnKeypress()
{
clearTimeout(timeout); //don't execute "next" after 5000 (or less) ms
next(); //run "next"
}

function next() 
{ 
//your code ..
}
</script>
<element onkeypress="elementOnKeypress();"></element><!-- element is your html-element to be keypressed -->
```

Comment: add explanation to your code please, and care on using global variables

Comment: Could you please explain what $("#element") means because when I executed this code, I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.  I also tried replacing it with document or element handle like the canvas.  I'm kind of new to javascript; will appreciate it really if you bear with me and explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The flow of your experiment, as I understood them, are this:

1. Show Stimulus
2. Check for keypresses repeatedly
3. If 5 seconds have passed, show next stimulus
4. If key was pressed, store keypress in array, then show next stimulus.

To do this, I would use [Keypress](http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/), a JS library for catching input.

You would first want to define your stimuli

E.g.:

```
var stimuli = ["Apple","Orange","Keira Knightley","Banana"];
```

You would then want to set up your `event` listeners. These will log your keypresses for you.

```
var listener = new window.keypress.Listener();
var results = [];
listener.simple_combo("shift s", function() {
    results.push("You pressed shift and s");
});
```

Then you want to set up the timing system. I would use a `setInterval()` function to increment the position in the array that the subject is in.

```
var pos = -1; //Arrays start at 0, and you want to run this function to start.
function nextStim() {
    pos = pos + 1;
    myDiv.innerHTML = stimuli[pos]
}
var results = [];
listener.simple_combo("shift s", function() {
    results.push("The stimulus was: " + stimuli[pos] + "And you pressed Shift + S" );
});
setInterval(nextStim,5000);
```